# Java JSONObject#has throwing exception

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio, json

I'm trying to check if a JSONObject has a specific key. Here is my code:

```
    JSONObject meta = App.meta();
    int sum = 0;
    JSONObject mapping;
    if(!meta.has("readMessagesMap")){  <--- this line jumps to...
        return 0;        <--- never called
    }else{
        try { <--- never called
            mapping = meta.getJSONObject("readMessagesMap");
            [...]
            return sum;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0; <--- ...directly to here
        }
    }
```

`meta` is a valid `JSONObject`:

[image]

When I'm stepping, the if statement, somehow, directly jumps to `return 0` line inside the catch block, without even entering try block. I have breakpoints on the try line, `e.printStackTrace` line, they are just not called. The stack trace isn't printed either. I have no idea why this is happening. I've restarted Android Studio and my app, but it's the same.

Comment: try returning a different value and print it.

Comment: From the calling code, is the return value zero, or is there an exception thrown?

Comment: @Blackbelt that's weird. I've made first if statement return -1 and the return statement in catch block return -2, even though debugger steps at other places, it returned -1. Is there a 'clean project' thing in Android Studio?

Comment: @nasch see my comment to Blackbelt.

Comment: I think the IDE is just showing you a confusing indicator of what's executing.  It sounds to me like that catch block is not really being executed, but for some reason the debugger shows the code stopping there.  I wouldn't worry about it if your logging and return values are doing what you expect.

Comment: it is what I expected. I guess it is something related to the android bytecode.

Comment: @nasch But I need to step and debug a complicated piece of code there.

Answer (score 0):

It was a symbol corruption issue. I've cleaned the project and it got away.